# Moving tabs in GVIM via mouse is not working

Tags: vim, tabs, nerdtree, xfce

I am using Vim in XFCE (Xubuntu). On my previous system Debian Testing there was no problem with moving tabs in NERDTree via mouse.

I have already set this in my `.vimrc`, but it's not working.

```
set mouse=a
```

Any idea how to fix that?
**PS:** I already know `:tabm X`, but sometimes I want to use mouse.

**EDIT**

I mean `GVIM`.

**EDIT #2**

Add `.vimrc`

```
@maci ➜  ~ rvm:(ruby-2.0.0)  cat .vimrc 
"""""""""""
" Options "
"""""""""""

set nocompatible " turn off compatibility with Vi

set hidden " hide buffers when not displayed

set nobackup " don't make a backup before overwriting a file.
set nowritebackup " ^^^
set noswapfile " don't need no stinky swapfiles
set directory=~/tmp,/tmp " keep swap files in one location

set confirm " confirm on quit, etc.
set autoread " automatically read changes from disk

set showcmd " display incomplete commands.
set history=1000 " remember more commands and search history

set softtabstop=2 " soft tab width
set tabstop=2 " global tab width
set shiftwidth=2 " number of spaces for (un)indenting
set shiftround " round indent to multiple of 'shiftwidth'
set expandtab " expand tab characters into spaces

set number! " Number lines

set mouse=a " enable mouse in GUI & terminal

" Leader
let mapleader = ","

" Search
set smartcase " Smartcase is better than ignorecase
set hlsearch " highlight matches...
set incsearch " ...as you type.


" Run NERDTree on ESC+t
function OpenNERDTree()
  execute ":NERDTree"
endfunction
command -nargs=0 OpenNERDTree :call OpenNERDTree()

nmap <ESC>t :OpenNERDTree<CR>

" " Solarized
" syntax enable
" if has('gui_running')
"   set background=dark
" else
"   set background=dark
" endif
" " let g:solarized_termcolors=256
" colorscheme solarized

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" COLOR
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
syntax enable
set t_Co=256 " 256 colors
set background=dark
color grb256
highlight Normal ctermfg=grey ctermbg=black


hi Search ctermbg=brown
hi Search guibg=brown

" Inconsolata
if has("gui_running")
  if has("gui_gtk2")
    set guifont=Inconsolata\ 11.5
  elseif has("gui_win32")
    set guifont=Consolas:h11:cANSI
  endif
endif

" 80 characters line
if exists('+colorcolumn')
  set colorcolumn=80
else
  au BufWinEnter * let w:m2=matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>80v.\+', -1)
endif

" Vundle setup
set nocompatible               " be iMproved
filetype off                   " required!

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required!
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

" My Bundles here:
Bundle 'tpope/vim-rails'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Bundle 'wincent/Command-T'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-rails.git'
Bundle 'bronson/vim-trailing-whitespace'
Bundle 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Bundle 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'
Bundle 'sickill/vim-pasta'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-haml'
Bundle 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Bundle 'kchmck/vim-coffee-script'
Bundle 'ervandew/supertab'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-endwise'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-surround'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Bundle 'jgdavey/vim-blockle'
Bundle 'vim-scripts/vim-json-bundle'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Bundle 'mattn/gist-vim'
Bundle 'vim-scripts/nginx.vim'
Bundle 'vim-scripts/matchit.zip'
Bundle 'vim-scripts/c.vim'
Bundle 'rking/ag.vim'
Bundle 'skalnik/vim-vroom'
Bundle 'tsaleh/vim-matchit'

au BufRead,BufNewFile /etc/nginx/* set ft=nginx

filetype on           " Enable filetype detection after Vundle
filetype indent on    " Enable filetype-specific indenting
filetype plugin on    " Enable filetype-specific plugins


" Fix bug with broken Omni completion
if has("autocmd")
  autocmd FileType ruby set omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete
  autocmd FileType ruby let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading=1
  autocmd FileType ruby let g:rubycomplete_classes_in_global=1
endif

" Disable arrow keys
"map <Left> <Nop>
"map <Right> <Nop>
"map <Up> <Nop>
"map <Down> <Nop>

set guioptions-=T

nnoremap <leader>g :Ag<Space>

" ARB templates
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.arb setfiletype ruby
```

Comment: Does the terminal emulator you are using support the mouse?

Comment: Yes. I can select some lines via mouse (automatically goes to visual mode).

Comment: I didn't even know that it was possible to move the tabs in CLI Vim with the mouse.

Comment: @romainl edited and added more info.. (GVIM!)

Comment: Tabs and NERDTree are almost totally unrelated anyway. Your problem is moving tabs with the mouse in GVim on Linux: you should clarify your question and also add the content of your `~/.vimrc`.